Autograd on a specific layer’s parameters
I am trying to get the Jacobian matrix of a specific layer's parameters. The below is my network model and i apply functional_call on it.
def fm(params, input):
    return functional_call(self.model, params, input.unsqueeze(0)).squeeze(0)
                
def floss(func_params, input):
    fx = fm(func_params, input)
    return fx

and I used to compute the Jacobian of all the parameters by this way
func_params = dict(self.model.named_parameters())
per_sample_grads = vmap(jacrev(floss, 0), (None, 0))(func_params, input)

Right now, I  need just get the gradient on a specific layer's parameters, here is my approach.
def grad(f, param):
    return torch.autograd.grad(f, param)    

out = vmap(floss, (None, 0))(func_params,input)
gradf = vmap(grad, (0, None))(out, func_params['model.0.weight'])

However, the error saying "element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn"
Because, i have tried
grad = self.grad(out[0], func_params['model.0.weight'])

and it works. I don't really know how to fix this problem.

Can you post a small example demonstrating your problem with the necessary imports and functions? It is hard to debug the problem if we do not know what vmap or functional_call is.
